# Ping time jumps from 0.9ms to between 11 and 28ms

Tags: networking, performance, ping

I have a server with 5 other devices all plugged into a single switch. I can ping all devices with nice low ping times (between 0.6ms and 0.9ms). But, all of a sudden, the ping time to one of the devices increases significantly (between 20ms to 80ms). We also see abnormal behaviour from the device consistent with bad connectivity (it's a specialist camera) when the ping rate deteriorates.

Unplugging the device from the switch and plugging it back in reduces the ping time back to its 'normal' 0.9ms. After a while, it jumps back up again.

We cannot identify any external event coincident with the start of the increased ping times.
All cables are cat6 structural.

It 'smells' like some kind of electrical interference, but it's weird that it works fine for a while, then goes bad, but goes back to normal when the cable is disconnected and reconnected.

Any ideas will be very welcome. Thanks!

(This is my first question here, so apologies in advance for any newbieness in the question)

Sample of arping output below:

```
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.952ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.951ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.955ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.941ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.952ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.952ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.951ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.951ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.941ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.984ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.950ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.952ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.952ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.951ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.952ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.942ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.953ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.953ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.942ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.946ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.927ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.942ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  0.957ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  11.573ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  35.059ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  21.710ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  21.187ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  19.604ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  17.873ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  36.197ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  29.025ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  28.685ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  24.288ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  28.241ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  21.027ms
    Unicast reply from 192.168.1.85 [00:40:7F:40:22:50]  21.241ms
```

Comment: What is the CPU usage of the device when this happens?

Comment: Also, have you connected another device to this circuit to see if it exhibits similar behavior?

Comment: switch vendor please :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions and comments.

It seems like it was a network cabling problem. The cable, although good quality, was routed next to some other cables carrying some particularly nasty interference. Cable was re-routed and problem went away.

Once again, thanks for your help and interest.